# How to put a condition in my pdo code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to do is when a user successfully registered my pdo will have a condition if its successful or not.

My problem how to put a if else condition in pdo if the user is successful or not in registering an account.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$name = @$_POST['name'];
$age = @$_POST['age'];
$address = @$_POST['address'];
$gender = @$_POST['gender'];
$imageName = @$_FILES['image']['name'];


$q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender, imageName ) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender, :image)";

$query = $dbc->prepare($q);
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->bindParam(':age', $age);
$query->bindParam(':address', $address);
$query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
$query->bindParam(':image', $imageName);


$results = $query->execute();

?>
```

Comment: What do you want to do if successful? If not?

Comment: Why are you using `@$_POST`?

Comment: What's with all the `@`? That's hardly going to help you with a successful registration... Name? Don't care. Age? Don't care... You get the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem how to put a if else condition in pdo if the user is successful or not in registering an account.

[`PDOStatement::execute()` returns boolean](http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues) true or false depending on the result.

You should be able to check `$results` for the results...

```
echo $results ? 'User successfully registered' : 'Error registering user!';
```